# How to Transpose each element in a 3D np array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 3D array a, I want to call np.tranpose on each of the element in its first index.
For example, given the array:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

I want:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```

Essentially I want to transpose each element inside the array. I tried to reshape it but I can't find a good way of doing it. Looping through it and calling transpose on each would be too slow. Any advice?

Comment: Read the `transpose` docs.  It takes a parameter.  Something like `a.transpose([0,2,1])`.

Comment: Is your array just filled with 1,2 and 3 as you show? If so, simple reshape will work: `arr.reshape(3,4,3)`

Comment: You example is ambiguous.  It could be a tranpose or a reshape case.

Comment: @julien In a general case in which matrix elements can be arbitrary, `reshape` doesn't work right? It is not the expected output of transposing a matrix.

Comment: @Francis yes, this would work only on the example given by OP, not in general case: `reshape` on  `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` will give `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` while `transpose` will give `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`. If input is `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]` like in example there would be no difference though.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the built-in numpy `transpose` method and directly specify the axes to transpose

```
>>> a = np.array([[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]],
                  [[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]],
                  [[3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3]]])

>>> print(a.transpose((0, 2, 1)))

[[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [3 3 3]
  [3 3 3]
  [3 3 3]]]
```