# How can I tranpose arrays in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Similar to the premise in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500216/how-to-transpose-each-element-in-a-3d-np-array), I'd like to transpose each sub-array in the matrix. However, my sub-arrays are of different sizes. I've tried the following lines of code:

```
import numpy as np

test_array = np.array([
       np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1]]),

       np.array([[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]),

       np.array([[3, 3],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 3]])
]) 

new_test_array = np.apply_along_axis(test_array, 0, np.transpose)
*** numpy.AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

new_test_array = np.transpose(test_array, (0, 2, 1))
*** ValueError: axes don't match array

new_test_array = np.array(list(map(np.transpose, test_array)))
returns original array
```

My expected output is

```
new_test_array = np.array([
   np.array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]]),

       np.array([[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]]),

       np.array([[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]])
])
```

Comment: Are the elements of `test_array` lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: `[np.transpose(x) for x in test_array]`

Comment: The 3 things you tried must have given different errors.  Be accurate if you real,y want help.

Comment: test_array is giving syntax error, would you check that?

Comment: @QuangHoang is asking a crucial question. `test_array` is some amorphous structure: a one-dimensional numpy-array of python-lists. The `test_array` dtype is object. That's something that I don't want to poke without a stick. OP, are you sure that you really are using proper structures?

Comment: @QuangHoang good catch, they should be numpy arrays. Once I've fixed that, I'm able to use the last line `new_test_array = np.array(list(map(np.transpose, test_array)))` to produce my desired output. Feel free to close if this isn't useful.

Comment: @zabop I copied and pasted what I entered and it seems to be fine...

Comment: @hpaulj You're right, I've updated my question. Once I updated the example following Quang Hoang's comment, the last line I tried ended up working.

Comment: The first 2 don't work because `test_array` is 1d, (3,) shape.  You can't transpose it directly.   `apply_along_axis` takes a function that expects a 1d array, and iterates on the others.  Hardly applicable here.  The `list(map(...))` works for the same reason the list comprehension does - iterates on the objects of the array, applying `np.transpose` to each.

Comment: "I copied and pasted what I entered and it seems to be fine..." yeah, after you edited it, ofc xD Your original post raises a `SyntaxError` because you missed one `]`, then you edited it some (dubious?) additional `np.array` calls. I suppose that @zabop and also myself were, 16 hours ago, using your first version of the post.

Answer (score 0):

To answer shortly, you can do this on your data to get what you want:

```
new_test_array = [np.transpose(x) for x in test_array]
```

But in your example you build an array of lists *instead* of an array of varying sizes (which is impossible in numpy). It is also why your methods did **not** work.

So if you want to do it in a more correct way, first you have to use a list and then convert each list into a numpy array, which you can then transpose individually.

Here's an example code:

```
test_list = [[[1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[2, 2, 2, 2],
              [2, 2, 2, 2],
              [2, 2, 2, 2]],

             [[3, 3],
              [3, 3],
              [3, 3]]]

list_of_arrays = [np.array(x) for x in test_list]
transposed_arrays = [np.transpose(x) for x in list_of_arrays]
```

Printing `transposed_arrays` will give you this:

```
[array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]]), 

 array([[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]]), 

 array([[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]])]
```

Comment: You could use OP's `test_array` as-is (it gives an esotheric data-structure, but semantically correct). And follow @hpaulj comment and do `[np.transpose(x) for x in test_array]`. The final result is the same. I wanted to point out that your answer is unnecessarily jumping through hoops for transforming data structures... `np.transpose` works for any kind of list-array, no need to convert things (at least recent numpy versions, I haven't tested old ones)

Comment: @MariusSiuram You're right, I'll add that one as an option.